# Use state, static defaultProps or a property to hold static data

Tags: reactjs

Currently, I have in my state a property holding the following value

```
state = {
  listOfCategories = ['Bank', 'Home', 'News']
}
```

That piece of state is never going to change (I will use it in that component and a direct children). So I'm thinking if I should remove it from the state, which to my understanding is meant for mutable data, and put it as a property of the Class or defaultProps of that Class.

Which approach should I follow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> That piece of state is never going to change

You can even extract `listOfCategories = ['Bank', 'Home', 'News']` completely outside of React tree (or put in a different file, to use it elsewhere as well).

> the state, which to my understanding is meant for mutable data,

The state should be immutable because React does "shallow check" (checks if reference has been changed, not the deep comparison, which checks for changed value for nested properties as well).

> a property of the Class or defaultProps of that Class.

If `listCategories` belongs to the current component, then it'd make sense to declare it as a property because `listCategories` is the component's own property, not changed by parent's props (as you said it never changes).

Answer (score 0):

Well i think every solution you expose are good.

But let's come back to basic :)

You create a class with react propertys but it still a simple class.
So why not just declare this array as member of this class like this :

```html
class test extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      test: props.FakeData
    }
    this.listOfCategories = ['Bank', 'Home', 'News']
  }
}
```

simple, easy and in my opinion the best way to do it.